# Firebase Security Rules newData does not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[image: database sample]

I'm trying to restrict the "Stores" write to the owner only, but the "write" rules does not seem to work

```
"Stores": { // restrict "Stores" write to the owner only
              ".read": "true",
              ".write": "auth.uid !== null && auth.uid === newData.child('ownerID').val()"
          }
```

... and surprisingly neither does this..

```
".write": "newData.child('ownerID').exists()"
```

However it works with this...

```
".write": "auth.uid !== null"
```

But it is not as secure as how I want it. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the rule on the wrong level. Right now you're controlling who can write to the `/Stores` node. But what you want to do, is control who can write an an individual store, so `/Stores/$storeid`.

Something like:

```
"Stores": {
    "$storeid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid !== null && auth.uid === newData.child('ownerID').val()"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! Why didn't I see it. And thank you for editing my Q tags too...